# How to show Room Index according RoomCombination using php in xml

Tags: php, xml, soap-client, credentials

How to display Hotel Rooms accordingly Room Combination room index.

I want to display the hotel room accordingly room combination array using php.

```
 <HotelRooms>
    <HotelRoom>
    <RoomIndex>1</RoomIndex>
    <RoomTypeName></RoomTypeName>
    <Inclusion></Inclusion>
    <RoomTypeCode></RoomTypeCode>
    <RatePlanCode></RatePlanCode>
    <RoomRate RoomFare="69.46" Currency="USD" AgentMarkUp="3.31" RoomTax="0" TotalFare="69.46"
    B2CRates="false">
    <DayRates>
    <DayRates Date="2014-03-29T00:00:00+05:30" BaseFare="69.46"/>
    </DayRates>
    <ExtraGuestCharges>0</ExtraGuestCharges>
    <ChildCharges>0</ChildCharges>
    <Discount>0</Discount>
    <OtherCharges>0</OtherCharges>
    <ServiceTax>0</ServiceTax>
    </RoomRate>
    <RoomAdditionalInfo MaxAdult="2" MaxChild="1">
    <Description></Description>
    <ImageURLs>
    <URL></URL>
    </ImageURLs>
    <Amenities>
    <Amenity>Coffee and Tea maker</Amenity>
    <Amenity>Color television</Amenity>
    <Amenity>Free Car</Amenity>
    </Amenities>
    </RoomAdditionalInfo>
    </HotelRoom>
    <HotelRoom>
    <RoomIndex>2</RoomIndex>
    <RoomTypeName>Single Room Standard Twin</RoomTypeName>
    <Inclusion>None</Inclusion>
    <RoomTypeCode>SB|0|0||001:NOV:2611:S3165:3514:13645|2</RoomTypeCode>
    <RatePlanCode>001:NOV:2611:S3165:3514:13645|NOV|SB</RatePlanCode>
    <RoomRate RoomFare="69.46" Currency="USD" AgentMarkUp="3.31" RoomTax="0" TotalFare="69.46"
    B2CRates="false">
    <DayRates>
    <DayRates Date="2014-03-29T00:00:00+05:30" BaseFare="69.46"/>
    </DayRates>
    Page 47 of 67
    TBOHolidays
    Hotel API 7.0
    Revision : 00
    <ExtraGuestCharges>0</ExtraGuestCharges>
    <ChildCharges>0</ChildCharges>
    <Discount>0</Discount>
    <OtherCharges>0</OtherCharges>
    <ServiceTax>0</ServiceTax>
    </RoomRate>
    <RoomAdditionalInfo SmokingPref="NonSmoking" MaxOccupancy="2">
    <Description>Private bathroom with a deep soaking bathtub &lt;br /&gt;Non-Smoking&lt;br /&gt;</Description>
    </RoomAdditionalInfo>
    </HotelRoom>
    <HotelRoom>
    <RoomIndex>3</RoomIndex>
    <RoomTypeName>Double Room Standard Triple with Child (5,13)</RoomTypeName>
    <Inclusion>None</Inclusion>
    <RoomTypeCode>DB|0|1|5,13|001:NOV:2611:S3165:3514:13635|3</RoomTypeCode>
    <RatePlanCode>001:NOV:2611:S3165:3514:13635|NOV|DB</RatePlanCode>
    <RoomRate RoomFare="97.57" Currency="USD" AgentMarkUp="4.65" RoomTax="0" TotalFare="97.57"
    B2CRates="false">
    <DayRates>
    <DayRates Date="2014-03-29T00:00:00+05:30" BaseFare="97.57"/>
    </DayRates>
    <ExtraGuestCharges>0</ExtraGuestCharges>
    <ChildCharges>0</ChildCharges>
    <Discount>0</Discount>
    <OtherCharges>0</OtherCharges>
    <ServiceTax>0</ServiceTax>
    </RoomRate>
    </HotelRoom>
    <HotelRoom>
    <RoomIndex>4</RoomIndex>
    <RoomTypeName>Single Room Standard Triple</RoomTypeName>
    <Inclusion>None</Inclusion>
    <RoomTypeCode>SB|0|0||001:NOV:2611:S3165:3514:13635|4</RoomTypeCode>
    <RatePlanCode>001:NOV:2611:S3165:3514:13635|NOV|SB</RatePlanCode>
    <RoomRate RoomFare="97.57" Currency="USD" AgentMarkUp="4.65" RoomTax="0" TotalFare="97.57"
    B2CRates="false">
    <DayRates>
    <DayRates Date="2014-03-29T00:00:00+05:30" BaseFare="97.57"/>
    </DayRates>
    <ExtraGuestCharges>0</ExtraGuestCharges>
    <ChildCharges>0</ChildCharges>
    <Discount>0</Discount>
    <OtherCharges>0</OtherCharges>
    <ServiceTax>0</ServiceTax>
    </RoomRate>
    <RoomAdditionalInfo SmokingPref="NonSmoking" MaxOccupancy="2">
    <Description>Private ba`enter code here`throom with a deep soaking bathtub &lt;br /&gt;Non-Smoking&lt;br /&gt;</Description>
    </RoomAdditionalInfo>
    </HotelRoom>
 </HotelRooms>
 <OptionsForBooking>
    <FixedFormat>true</FixedFormat>
    <RoomCombination>
    <RoomIndex>1</RoomIndex>
    <RoomIndex>2</RoomIndex>
    </RoomCombination>
    <RoomCombination>
    <RoomIndex>3</RoomIndex>
    <RoomIndex>4</RoomIndex>
    </RoomCombination>
 </OptionsForBooking>
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Please show input and excpected output more clearly.

Comment: you can read from this link to response multiple rooms
http://api.tbotechnology.in/AIS_AvailableHotelrooms.aspx

Comment: Thanks for reply Stefan Hegny.
Actually i have xml api in which multiple rooms of hotel shows when i have options for multiple rooms means i have book 2 rooms then there is probability to books rooms index wise.
there is Shows list RoomIndex 1,2,3,4 etc and these rooms shows with combinations like this [1,3],[1,4] etc
you can understand from this link what's my requirement
http://api.tbotechnology.in/AIS_AvailableHotelrooms.aspx